# accessing C# base class in iterator causes ReSharper warning

Tags: c#, iterator, resharper, ienumerable, warnings

I have two classes, `GenericList` and `SpecificList`, where `SpecificList` inherits from `GenericList`.  `GenericList` implements `IEnumerable<GenericItem>` and `SpecificList` implements `IEnumerable<SpecificItem>`.  `SpecificItem` inherits from `GenericItem`.  I have to implement `GetEnumerator` in both `GenericList` and `SpecificList` since they implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  In `GenericList`, it's easy enough, I just return the enumerator for the underlying `List<T>`:

```
public IEnumerator<GenericItem> GetEnumerator()
{
    return genericItemsList.GetEnumerator();
}
```

However, in `SpecificList`, it seems trickier.  It seems risky to cast `IEnumerator<GenericItem>` to `IEnumerator<SpecificItem>`, and I don't know if that would even work.  Instead, I did the following:

```
public new IEnumerator<SpecificItem> GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerator<GenericItem> enumerator = base.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return (SpecificItem)enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

This compiles fine and a simple MSTest unit test calling `SpecificList.GetEnumerator()` seems to show it works.  However, ReSharper highlights `base` in the above method with the following warning:

> Access to GenericList.GetEnumerator through 'base' keyword from anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression or iterator results in unverifiable code

Is this something I should worry about?  Should I do something differently?

**Edit:**  I'm using ReSharper 5.1 Full Edition Pre-Release Build 5.1.1715.35.

Also, I should take a break from running MSTest unit tests:  I just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Chrome to reload the page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R# is correct that accessing the `base` keyword inside an iterator / lambda in the 3.0 version of the C# compiler could result in unverifiable code.  When it does or doesn't is a bit complex and I won't attempt to cover it here.

The easiest way to work around this is to wrap the call to `base.GetEnumerator` in another non-static private method and reference that from your iterator.

```
private IEnumerator<GenericItem> GetBaseEnumerator() {
  return base.GetEnumerator();
}

public new IEnumerator<SpecificItem> GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerator<GenericItem> enumerator = GetBaseEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return (SpecificItem)enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly certain this bug was fixed in the 4.0 version of the C# compiler.

Comment: Thanks.  Possibly a dumb question, but does the version of the C# compiler I'm using depend on the version of .NET I'm using?  It's a .NET 3.5 project--does that guarantee me a certain version of the C# compiler?

Comment: @Sarah, it's more tied to the version of Visual Studio you are running than the framework you are targeting.  2008 = C# 3.0 and 2010 = C# 4.0

Comment: aha!  I'm in 2008 SP1.  Your suggestion removes the ReSharper warning, and all seems to work.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems risky to cast `IEnumerator<GenericItem>` to `IEnumerator<SpecificItem>`, and I don't know if that would even work.

Sure it would.

```
return base.Cast<SpecificItem>().GetEnumerator();
```

No more or less risky than your current implementation. In fact, I'm pretty sure it's more-or-less the same code under the hood.

Comment: That makes Visual Studio 2008 angry.  `Cast` is highlighted in red and it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'Cast'".

Comment: @Sarah - You may need to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @ChaosPandion:  there's already a `using` directive for `System.Linq`.