# .NET Linq to Objects strange behavior

Tags: .net, exception, linq-to-objects

I've got a BadImageFormatException error in this little code below. I know it isn't good practice to write a program in this way but it seems to be a bug in .NET Framework, not in my code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b = new B();
            var bb = b.Test();
            var bbb = bb.Count();
        }
    }

    class A<T>
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Test()
        {
            yield return default(T);
        }
    }

    class B : A<int>
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> Test()
        {
            base.Test();
            yield return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: That's a highly unlikely problem to get from logic only, and highly unlikely to be a .NET bug. What changes do you have to make to get that code to execute (in other words, what specific change triggers the problem)?

Comment: Though I can reproduce the problem. Interesting...

Comment: if you had Resharper it would complain about `base.Test()` line. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136121/accessing-c-base-class-in-iterator-causes-resharper-warning

Comment: The compiler does try to help you out: `Access to member 'ConsoleApplication1.A<T>.Test()' through a 'base' keyword from an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or iterator results in unverifiable code. Consider moving the access into a helper method on the containing type.` I've never seen the framework tell you that you've got "unverifiable" code, but it sounds to me like it's unpredictable behavior. I don't get the exception myself, just the compiler warning.

Comment: @Eranga: Ah, I wish I saw that question earlier.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note, you should be declaring `B.Test()` method as an override, but that's a different issue.

Commenting out the line `base.Test();` fixes it.  Here's my theory.

The problem is that you are implementing `B.Test()` using a compiler generated iterator.  Part of the process is taking your code and creating a state machine using a private nested class.  It would appear that the compiler team did not expect a use case where you would call the base implementation of anything within the iterator.

So in effect your code which is like this:

```
class B : A<int>
{
    public override IEnumerable<int> Test()
    {
        base.Test();
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

will require an iterator created by the compiler and will translate your lines to make an appropriate state machine.  It does not recognize the `base` call so it must have been copied verbatim.  The generated class naturally wouldn't inherit from any other class therefore the `base` call would fail.  Conceptually, the state machine code will have the line somewhere:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <Test>d__0 : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
    bool MoveNext()
    {
        // ...
        base.Test(); // what, base?
        // ...
    }
}
```

Though looking at the code generated using Reflector it doesn't actually appear in the assembly (at least, I don't see it).

I wrote a different test case to determine what line it causes a problem:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Starting");
using (var e = bb.GetEnumerator())
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
}
```

And stepped through the code.  It fails on the first `MoveNext()` call (as I would have thought).  Unfortunately I don't know how to step into the generated iterator.  So stepping through the disassembled code, it fails on the marked line:

```
            System.Console.WriteLine("Starting");
00000075  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[03622088h] 
0000007b  call        63474D1C 
00000080  nop 
            using (var e = bb.GetEnumerator())
00000081  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-44h] 
00000084  call        dword ptr ds:[001E0020h] 
0000008a  mov         dword ptr [ebp-58h],eax 
0000008d  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-58h] 
00000090  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax 
            {
00000093  nop 
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
00000094  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
00000097  call        dword ptr ds:[001E0024h]     // ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
0000009d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-5Ch],eax 
000000a0  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-5Ch] 
000000a3  call        63A48640 
000000a8  nop 
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
000000a9  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
000000ac  call        dword ptr ds:[001E0028h] 
000000b2  mov         dword ptr [ebp-60h],eax 
000000b5  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-60h] 
000000b8  call        63A49388 
000000bd  nop
```

So maybe the actual problem might be something else *but* it'll probably be related to this `base` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
you need to create a delegate method to call the base.Test() method.
Also you should use the Test method as override or new.

```
class A<T>
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Test()
        {
            yield return default(T);
        }
    }

    class B : A<int>
    {
        public new IEnumerable<int> Test()
        {
            this.MyDelegate();           
            yield return 0;
        }
        private void MyDelegate()
        {
            base.Test();
        }
    }
    public class CompassModel
    {
        public void GetTeamLeadData()
        {
            var b = new B();
            var bb = b.Test();
            var bbb = bb.Count();
        }
    }
```

For reference.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHBADIMAGEFORMAT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true